# Dynamically allocate 2D char array, and create a copy of itself

Tags: arrays, c, string, segmentation-fault

I have to dynamically allocate a 2d char array where the number of columns and lines are given by the user. After that, I need to create a copy of that 2d char array so I can manipulate its data.

This is how I tried it. When I try to print the copy array, it prints ok, but it gives me a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error. Not sure what I have to do here.

```
    char **original;

    original = malloc(sizeof(char *) * lines);

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < columns; i++)
    {
        original[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * columns+ 1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            scanf(" %c", &original[i][j]);
        }
    }

     //The following happens inside a different function. The original matrix was passed as a parameter.
    char **copy = NULL ;
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
        copy[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * columns+ 1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
            strcpy(copy[i],original[i]);
    }
```

Comment: `strcpy(copy[i],original[i]);` fails as `original[i]` does not certainly point to a _string_.  luis2608,  How is `copy` to be used in later observable code?

Answer (score 0):

The first for is not correct you should do it on lines not column.
You can also copy with memcpy. or copy char by char.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
    char **original;
    int lines = 3;
    int columns = 2;
    
    original = malloc(sizeof(char *) * lines);

    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
        original[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * columns);
    }   
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            scanf(" %c", &original[i][j]);
        }   
    }   
    
    //The following happens inside a different function. The original matriz was passed as a parameter.
    char **copy = malloc(sizeof(char *) * lines);
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
        copy[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * columns);
    }   
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            copy[i][j] = original[i][j];
        }   
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried that out, but I still get the segmentation fault error.

Comment: Adding a main, no error on valgrind (just memory lost normal on this ) Can you share your main and or test it with valgrind ?